# How to get a list of alerts on MOSS 07

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, alert, stsadm

I need help getting a list of alerts on a MOSS 07 server.

I'm trying to use STSADM.

I saw the getproperty command for STSADM so I tried.

`STSADM -o getproperty -pv alerts-enabled -url http://intranet/`

All it did was throw an error.

so it tried

`STSADM -o getproperty -url http://intranet/`

And found a list of property values.

I'm not sure what I should do to get a list of current alerts in the site collection.

Comment: what you want, to get all the alerts configured on list? or you want to make sure alerts are enabled?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I want a list of all the alerts, in the site collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the pwoershell to get the alerts for a site collection.

1. First you make sure [powershell is properly configured.](http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2007/09/03/preparing-powershell-for-sharepoint-and-moss-2007/)
2. Now run the [below script](http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/Find-all-Alerts-in-a-Site-Collection-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx) and you will get it.

   Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

   ```
   $site = Get-SPSite "http://dlvrn2010.com/sites/spalerts/                    
   $alertResultsCollection = @()

   foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) {  

         foreach ($alert in $web.Alerts){

         $alertURL = $web.URL + "/" + $alert.ListUrl

          $alertResult = New-Object PSObject

     $alertResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "List URL" -value $alertURL

      $alertResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Alert Title" -value alert.Title

      $alertResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Alert Type" -value $alert.AlertType

      $alertResult | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name "Subscribed User" -value $alert.User
         $alertResultsCollection += $alertResult

        }

     }

     $site.Dispose()
    $alertResultsCollection
   ```

   Export to CSV

   $alertResultsCollection | Export-CSV "Alerts.csv"

you can use the script from this `[codeplex solution][3]` also check this [User on SharePoint 2007 getting alert that was/is not set up](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83804/user-on-sharepoint-2007-getting-alert-that-was-is-not-set-up)

Comment: Was PowerShell ever supported for 2007 though?

Comment: I am not sure about it whether it is supported or not but i give the instruction how to configure powershell.